# Direction on Map

Tags: ios4

i have show route between two points on mkmapview in my application but i want to show direction of these two points. the latitude and longtitude of poitns are store in NSArray.

Answer (score 0):

This may be too late and you probably have solved it already, but here is a solution that I have tested and does work correctly.

I say that as other implementations I have tried have given results off by about 25degress.

newLocation is obtained from the CLLocationManagerDelegate and the latlngofAnn was the selected MKAnnotation the user selects in my app.

Just replace the lat and lon data with whats in your array.

```
double lat2 =  latlngOfAnn.coordinate.latitude * M_PI / 180.0;
double lon2 =  latlngOfAnn.coordinate.longitude * M_PI / 180.0;
double lat1 =  newLocation.coordinate.latitude * M_PI / 180.0;
double lon1 =  newLocation.coordinate.longitude * M_PI / 180.0;

double dLon = lon2 - lon1;
double y = sin(dLon) * cos(lat2);
double x = cos(lat1) * sin(lat2) - sin(lat1) * cos(lat2) * cos(dLon);
double radiansBearing = atan2(y, x);

if(radiansBearing < 0.0)
    radiansBearing += 2*M_PI;

double bearing = radiansBearing * 180.0 / M_PI;
```